# Execute multiple git commands

Tags: git, git-merge

In my current project, we have a requirement wherein we have to do the reverse merge from release specific branch (`release-0815`) to release post each prod deployment.

This needs to be done across multiple repositories that has `release-0815` branch. Currently, what I do it go to each of these repositories and execute below commands one by one:

```
git checkout release
git merge release-0815 --no-ff --no-edit
git push origin release
```

Is there a way to loop through a list of repositories and execute the above commands as a single command?

Comment: Yes, write a batch (CMD, powershell, bash, or whatever interpreter you have) script

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to loop through a list of repositories and execute above commands as a single command?

You will need a script to loop over the multiple repositories which can be written in any language.

Your script can be in sh,bash, python etc

To execute multiple git commands us the `&&` operator

```
git checkout release && git merge release-0815 --no-ff --no-edit && git push origin release
```

but since you are doing rebase and merge it's not recommended in case you have conflicts

#### Sample script

```
for path in `<repositores list>`; 
    do 
        cd $path; git checkout release && git merge release-0815 --no-ff --no-edit && git push origin release 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

To execute above commands as a single command, you can put `&&` between each command if you are on Linux or using Git Bash:

```
git checkout release && git merge release-0815 --no-ff --no-edit && git push origin release
```

If any of the commands fails, all execution will stop.

To iterate over multiple repos, you can write a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure about loop, but there is a way to join git commands:
Or wrap into the sh script and do anything.

```
git checkout release && git merge release-0815 --no-ff --no-edit && git push origin release
```

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose that your repos list is in `repos.txt`:

```
~/repo1
~/repo2
~/repo3
```

## Loop through all your repos

> Is there a way to loop through a list of repositories ...

### loop repos in `bash`

```sh
cat $repo_list| while read repo; do
 <your command>
done
```

## Execute as single command

> ... and execute the above commands as a single command?

```sh
git checkout release && git merge release-0815 --no-ff --no-edit && git push origin release
```

## check if repo has specific branch

> This needs to be done across multiple repositories that has `release-0815` branch.

`git branch -a | grep 'release-0815' && <foo>`

## let's put it together

```sh
release_name='release-0815'
cat $repo_list | while read repo; do
 git branch -a | grep $release_name && git checkout release && git merge $release_name --no-ff --no-edit && git push origin 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the repositories are within the same directory, let's say something like:

```
projects/repo1
projects/repo2
projects/repo3
```

Some times I found convenient to use the [`find`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) command, for example, to update all repositories I do something like:

```
$ cd projects
```

And then:

```
$ find . -type d -depth 1 -exec git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} pull \;
```

Now If I would like to run more commands per project I could use multiple times the option `-exec`, for example:

```
$ find . -type d -depth 1 \
-exec git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} pull \; \
-exec git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} remote -v \;
```

In your case probably could be something like:

```
$ find . -type d -depth 1 \
-exec git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} checkout release \; \
-exec git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} merge release-0815 --no-ff --no-edit \; \
-exec git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} push origin release \;
```

Note that in this case, the second command will only run if the first one returns successfully.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, all repositories are on my local and I run simple batch script to pull latest changes before running merge from Release specific branch to release branch.